# Stars and Bars problem with conditions

Tags: combinations

> $50$  prizes to be  distribute among  $4$ teams  $A$ ,$B$, $C$ ,$D$ , provided that   the team $A$ gets $15$ prizes  at most ; and team B gets $20$ prizes at most,  How many ways could we do that ?

My try follows  : answer by complement ; By using Stars and Bars:

> $A+B+C+D=50$

Total number  of  ways to distribute $50$ prizes  onto $4$ teams = $53C3$

> 1) Ways that $A \geq 16$  : $A'+B'+C'+D'=34  \to  37C3$
>
> 2) Ways that $B \geq 21$  : $A'+B'+C'+D'=29  \to  32C3$
>
> {Intersection between  1&2     $A'+B'+C'+D'=13 \to  16C3$
>
> Answer = $53C3 - (37C3 +32C3-16C3)$

Is my answer right?

If not, please help me understand my fault.

Thank you for your help

Comment: In line 2), you should have said $\color{red}{B} \geq 21$.  Otherwise, your solution is correct.